# Cant't tilt plane following nurbs curve to certain angle, rotating control points

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I want to rotate a NURBS curve control points. On it there is a plane following de curve. If I tilt the control point for example to 90 degree, it rotates like to 80 degree. And to set it like 90 I have to put it to 140 degree. With bezier curves there's no problem. I put 90 degree to tilt bezier and it tilts exactly 90.

[image]

Here the NURBS curves tilt images
[image: trying to rotate 90 degree but looks like 80]

[image: here a frontal view]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! I can't see a direct connection to *Geonetry Nodes* here, and it's not clear what exactly you're trying to do (a screenshot of your node tree would be helpful), but basically you'd have to use the node `Set Curve Normal` to align the normals of the points all to *Z Up* first to get absolute values relative to the global axis.

Comment: thanks, i put other two images on the post for better xplanation. How i can do this? "you'd have to use the node Set Curve Normal to align the normals of the points all to Z Up first to get absolute values relative to the global axis"

Comment: Are you using a *Geometry Nodes* modifier here at all, or not? If yes, then please show us a screenshot of your current node tree. If not, then take a closer look at the value for "Twist Method" in the *Object Data Properties* of the curve.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to import .blend here to check it. Basically i only did what is on the picture on top of post. Straight nurbs curve, with 7 control points. Added array modifier and curve modifier. Selected one of the middle nodes on the curve and tilted to 90 degree. And happens that tilts like 80 degree

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the [tag:geometry-nodes] tag, since you're obviously not working with *Geometry Nodes* here. Please complete your question with the necessary information. You can also upload your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com and add the link generated there to your question.

Comment: okey, i added the .blend file on top of the post. thx. You can see on file that i tilt the node to 90 degree but doesn't look like 90 degree

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal behavior of a [NURBS curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) because it consists of control points and the values for Tilt assigned to them are interpolated when resampling and converting to a mesh.

A value of $90°$ becomes a value of exactly $60°$ and to get an angle of $90°$ you would have to set the *Tilt* to $135°$.

If you need the exact tilt values of the points, you would have to use a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) instead, where only the intermediate points are interpolated.